# Ionic view + OpenFB

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view, openfb

I have an app that uses openFB.
while running it with ionic serve, it works fine.
When I try to test it with Ionic view the facebook login page doesn't come up.

any idea how to solve it?

Thanks!
Sophain.

Answer (score 2):

openFB working only on app not in browser, if you want login with facebook then using [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com) plugins